# Trying to use MSBuild from command line for WP7 solution

Tags: windows-phone-7, msbuild, pre-build-event

I'm attempting to build a WP7 solution file form the command line using MSBuild (the solution file builds perfectly fine inside VS). So far I have the following:

```
msbuild Test.WP7.sln /t:rebuild /p:OutputPath="bin\Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:Configuration="Release"
```

The problem I am having is a pre build step to install any NuGet packages required, the tool is reference by relative directory different from the solution file:

```
..\Tools\NuGet\nuget install $(ProjectDir)packages.config -o $(SolutionDir)Packages
```

Now when run from the command line MSBuild can't find this directory and returns a MSB3073 error like:

*"C:\Work\test\trunk\test\test.WP7.sln" (rebuild target) (1) ->
"C:\Work\test\trunk\test\test.Core.View.ViewModel\test.Core.View.ViewModel.csproj" (Rebuild target) (4) ->
  c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(902,9): error MSB3073: The command "..\Tools\NuGet\nuget install C:\Work\test\trunk\test\test.Core.View.ViewModel\packages.config -o C:\Work\test\trunk\test\Packages" exited with code 3. [C:\Work\test\trunk\test\test.Core.View.ViewModel\test.Core.View.ViewModel.csproj]*

Any ideas how I can get round this without changing the project or solution files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a relative path for NuGet. Instead use the `$(SolutionDir)` variable, like this:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)packages.config')" 
          Command="&quot;$(SolutionDir)Tools\nuget.exe&quot; install &quot;$(ProjectDir)packages.config&quot; -o &quot;$(SolutionDir)Packages&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Comment: But you specified it as relative to your build location. So unless you build in the right folder, it shouldn't work. Use `$(SolutionDir)\..\Tools\NuGet\nuget.exe` instead. But that said, you *should* have the nuget.exe tool as part of your solution, and not as a global asset!

Comment: sorted after i changed the path to use the '$(SolutionDir)..\Tools'